# When Item Deleted Recalculate Total Price on Flutter

Tags: flutter

hi guys i am doing a food order app i need some help while user deleted an item from cart then i should calculate the price is automaticly if you have any suggestions please let me know thanks
I already trıed  refreshın page when clıcked deleted button ıt works but i think i could  do tahw witohut push function

```
                             import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
            import 'package:resat/BurgerListView/const/themeColor.dart';
            import 'dart:convert';
            import 'DataTableDemo.dart';
            import 'Employee.dart';
            import 'services.dart';

            class FavoritesPage extends StatefulWidget {
              @override
              FavoritesPageState createState() => FavoritesPageState();
            }

            class FavoritesPageState extends State<FavoritesPage> {
              List<Employee> _employees;

              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return new MaterialApp(
                  theme: new ThemeData(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                  home: new Scaffold(
                    body: new Center(
                      //FutureBuilder is a widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot
                      // of interaction with a Future.
                      child: new FutureBuilder<List<Employee>>(
                        future: Services.getEmployees(),
                        //we pass a BuildContext and an AsyncSnapshot object which is an
                        //Immutable representation of the most recent interaction with
                        //an asynchronous computation.
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            List<Employee> _employee = snapshot.data;
                            Services.getEmployees();
                            return  Scaffold(
                              body: SafeArea(
                                child: CustomListView(_employee),
                              ),
                              bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(_employee),
                            );
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                          }
                          //return  a circular progress indicator.
                          return new CircularProgressIndicator();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }

            class CustomListView extends StatefulWidget {
              List<Employee> _employee;

              CustomListViewState createState() => CustomListViewState();

              CustomListView(this._employee);
            }

            class CustomListViewState extends State<CustomListView> {
              List<Employee> _employee;

              Widget build(context) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _employee.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
                    return createViewItem(_employee[currentIndex], context);
                  },
                );
              }

              @override
              void initState() {
                _employee = [];
                _getEmployees();
              }

              Widget createViewItem(Employee _employee, BuildContext context) {
                return new Card(
                    child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: new Image.asset(_employee.path, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      title: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            _employee.firstName,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 19.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text('-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0)),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                              Text(_employee.quantity),
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text(
                                  '+',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      subtitle: new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Services.deleteEmployee(_employee.id);
                                _getEmployees();

                                /*
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context){
                                          return new FavoritesPage();
                                        }
                                    )
                                );
                                */
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            ),
                            new Text('\$' + _employee.price.toString(),
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                          ]),

                      //trailing: ,
                      onTap: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                ));
              }

              void _getEmployees() {
                Services.getEmployees().then((employees) {
                  setState(() {
                    _employee = employees;
                  });
                  print("Length ${employees.length}");
                });
              }
            }

            class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
              @override
              BottomBarState createState() => BottomBarState(this._employee);

              final List<Employee> _employee;
              BottomBar(this._employee);


            }

            class BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar>{
              final List<Employee> _employee;

              BottomBarState(this._employee);

              @override
              void initState() {
                returnTotalAmount(_employee);
              }



              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, bottom: 25),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      totalAmount(_employee),
                      nextButtonBar(),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }

              Container totalAmount(List<Employee> _employee) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Total:",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "\$${returnTotalAmount(_employee)}",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 28),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }

              String returnTotalAmount(List<Employee> _employee) {
                double totalAmount = 0.0;

                for (int i = 0; i < _employee.length; i++) {
                  totalAmount = totalAmount + (double.parse(_employee[i].price)*double.parse(_employee[i].quantity));
                }
                return totalAmount.toString();

              }

              Container nextButtonBar() {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Themes.color, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "15-25 min",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Text(
                        "Next",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: When you are deleteing, you need to remove employee price right? and calculation part in separate where delete action in separate class?

Comment: Bottombar class is the calculation function of the list i just need call that class or refresh it

Comment: you can pass a callback function with the total price variable from parent class of the widget and when action triggered on child invoke that callback. Thats the easy method. Or you can use ValueChange or packages like provider, redux

Answer (score 0):

Honestly copying the code to my editor was one challenge and the number of needing widgets and class was the other one, so I did a minimal one and hope it solves your problem.

Here I have a list of double numbers and two Future functions, one returns all the items and the other one delete one item from the list.

I made `ListTile` for each item and if the user taps on the delete icon, it will be removed from the list and the sum will be recalculated again.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<List<double>> getData() async {
    return items;
  }

  Future<double> removeIt(int index) async {
    return items.removeAt(index);
  }

  List<double> items = [100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<double>>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<double>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text('Items : ${snapshot.data[index]}'),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await removeIt(index);
                          setState(() {});
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child:
                      Text('Sum is: ${snapshot.data.fold(0, (a, b) => a + b)}'),
                )
              ],
            );

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```